# In door ice maker quit working after water was turned off for a few days (Whirlpool)

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a Whirlpool french door refrigerator (model WRX988SIBM) with the ice dispenser in the door of the refrigerator and it quit making ice the other day when I had to cut off my water for a few days to fix a leak (unrelated).  I am not sure if these events are necessarily related but seeing as they happened around the same time I am wondering if it could be part of the problem.

The freezer temperature reads/is set at 0 when I check on the menu and I do not feel any water or any ice at all when I put my hand into the ice maker. I have not disconnected or turned off the water to the refrigerator, only to the house and the water dispenser still works properly. I have confirmed it is not the filter causing the issue.

Could this issue have been caused by the ice maker not having access to water for a few days? I can't think of anything else to try, if there are any other ideas on how I can get this working short of calling a Whirlpool tech please let me know.

Comment: My guess is that you dislodged some debris when you shut off the water, and it clogged the refrigerator line at some point. Maybe disconnect at the valve and check that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a look. Since I am getting water fine out of the water dispenser I would assume that would be fine but it's easy enough to check.

Comment: I have a different brand, but it’s worth mentioning, if water pressure is interrupted mine won’t  make ice till again until it’s turned off and back on, via a switch on the ice maker itself.  It’s listed as a “feature” in the manual but I can’t figure out how having to remember that infrequently needed task is a feature.

Comment: @Tyson: I believe the feature is to prevent contamination during a boil-order type situation, after the water line goes down.

Comment: @dandavis that makes sense actually.  I wonder why they don’t explain that—they just call it “water stop” and don’t explain why it necessary. (Up until now I’ve always wonder why that would be a feature.)

Comment: We have had the same problem every time the plumber shuts off water in house since we have been renovating our bathrooms.....the ice maker stops working. The water leaks out of ice maker into the switches and everything freezes up. The only way to get it working again is to shut off the freezer an use a hair dryer on the control box where the ice maker switches are. I do this until water stops dripping out of controls, everything dries up and switches move freely again. Turn freezer back on and as soon as the temp gets to 0 it starts making ice again. ...when water in house is shut off again f

Answer (score 6):

I have a GE side by side.  During the Texas deep freeze of 2021 we were very lucky, we never lost power.  However, we did lose water for a day or two.  When the water came back on, the Ice maker no longer made ice.  The problem was the tube which dispenses the water into the ice tray, froze up when water no longer moved through it every so often.  All I had to do was blow a hair dryer on in for a few minutes and the ice plug melted and water could once again flow into the ice tray.

Comment: Freezing makes sense but if it was just the lack of movement, if would freeze up if you didn't use ice for a while either.

Answer (score 2):

I have GE side by side refrigerator, too, that sometimes doesn’t dispense water. An appliance repairman told me to leave the freezer door open for 20 minutes to defrost the water supply line. If that doesn’t work at first, continue to defrost the water line; your frozen food will not defrost in that time. This hack has worked twice for me. However, if water isn’t being dispensed, it’s probably not making any ice either. By defrosting the water supply line, it should supply  water to the ice maker.